# Different Set collection based in different equals / hashcode

Tags: java

I want to have two `Set` collections holding unique objects based on different implementations of the `equals`/`hashCode` for the same kind of object.

For example, one `Set` would be only for the elements that have a different timestamp and the `equals` should return `a.timestamp!=b.timestamp`, but the other set could be only for elements that have different names with equals like `a.name!=b.name`.

Is there a trivial way to achieve this? How can you make custom equals for each different `Set`?

Comment: You want to have both lists of same object? Why don't create a parent `object` with all atributes you need and then implement two objects than inherit from first with different equals and hash?

Comment: @JordiCastilla why not post your comment as an answer and get the reputation for it?!

Comment: I'm currently shocked that a Set can't eat a comparator. From this problem it just would be so logical.

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki `TreeSet` does and can indeed by abused to do this, but it violates the `Map` contract and its own javadoc, which says that it's supposed to rely on `a.equals(b)`

Comment: Well, since such an obvious requirement, i'm sure there is a Set implementation that handles Comparators. That would be your best chance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting sounds like an abuse of the `equals` method and the `Set` interface.

Your use case defines two categories by which objects of a given type can be grouped (timestamp and name), and you wish to have two Sets, each holding at most a single instance for each category.

To do that, it would make more sense to have helper Sets :

```
Set<String> timestamps;
Set<String> names;
```

Then you can add names and timestamps to those sets, and use them to check if an object should be added to the target Collections (which don't have to be Sets).

For example :

```
List<SomeClass> timestampCategories = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
List<SomeClass> nameCategories = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
for (SomeClass object : inputCollection) {
    if (!timestamps.contains(object.getTimestamp()) {
        timestamps.add(object.getTimestamp());
        timestampCategories.add(object);
    }
    if (!names.contains(object.getName()) {
        names.add(object.getName());
        nameCategories.add(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually not solving the initial question.

Comment: @SimonZambrovski You could use Sets for the output collections, but I don't think it is necessary, and I believe my suggestion is the correct way to get the requested functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Create two wrapping value classes and put the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations there.

```
    public class Test {


    Set<NameBeanWrapper> names = new HashSet<Test.NameBeanWrapper>();
    Set<TimestampBeanWrapper> timestamps = new HashSet<Test.TimestampBeanWrapper>();

    public void store(Set<Bean> initial) {
      for (Bean bean : initial) {
        names.add(new NameBeanWrapper(bean));
        timestamps.add(new TimestampBeanWrapper(bean));
      }
    }

    public static class Bean {
      String name;
      Long timestamp;
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
      public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
      }
      public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
      }
    }

    public static class NameBeanWrapper {
      final Bean bean;
      public NameBeanWrapper(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
      }
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((bean == null || bean.name == null) ? 0 : bean.name.hashCode());
        return result;
      }
      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
          return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
          return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
          return false;
        }
        NameBeanWrapper other = (NameBeanWrapper) obj;
        if (bean == null) {
          if (other.bean != null) {
            return false;
          }
        }else if (bean.name == null) {
            if (other.bean.name != null) {
              return false;
            }
        } else if (!bean.name.equals(other.bean.name)) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }

    public static class TimestampBeanWrapper {
      final Bean bean;
      public TimestampBeanWrapper(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
      }
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((bean == null || bean.timestamp == null) ? 0 : bean.timestamp.hashCode());
        return result;
      }
      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
          return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
          return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
          return false;
        }
        NameBeanWrapper other = (NameBeanWrapper) obj;
        if (bean == null) {
          if (other.bean != null) {
            return false;
          }
        }else if (bean.timestamp == null) {
            if (other.bean.timestamp != null) {
              return false;
            }
        } else if (!bean.timestamp.equals(other.bean.timestamp)) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: If you want to compare, there is an external `Comparator`, but there is no external analogy for `equals` or `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested:

You want to have both lists of same object? Why don't create a parent `object` with all atributes you need and then implement two objects than inherit from first with different equals and hash?

Comment: Won't work if you want an element in both sets while keeping the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was wondering if there could be an easy way to specify the equals/hashcode to be used in a Set. I see no one has ever heard of such thing.

If this cannot be done, I can always use Map with the custom hashcode as key and then when I need to get the Collection I get the Map.values(). I wanted to avoid this because to keep memory usage low, but maybe it's the way...

Comment: you can create a custom set to solve the issue with a strategy of hashCode/equals but it is too much work. you will do just fine with what @JordiCastilla (or SimonZambrovski) suggested.